# Catastrophic generator matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Given the generator matrix $$G(z) = [z^3+1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ z^3+z^2+z+1]$$

Why is G(z) catastrophic?

I know that a generator matrix for a rate k/n convolutional code is called catastrophic, if there exists an information sequence $m(z) \in F_2^k[[z]]$ with infinitely many nonzero digits, that results in a codeword $c(z) \in F_2^n[[z]]$ with only finitely many nonzero digits.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polynomial generator matrix is catastrophic if and only if its (full rank) minors have a non-trivial common divisor. Here the entries have a common divisor
$$
\gcd(z^3+1,z^3+z^2+z+1)=\gcd((z+1)(z^2+z+1),(z+1)^3)=z+1,
$$
so this is, indeed, the case.

Because this is a $(2,1)$-code, we immediately see that the infinite weight input
$$
m(z)=\frac1{1+z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots
$$
will serve as an example. For a higher rank code there would be a bit more work to do.

Leaving it to you to find the corresponding finite weight codeword.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful answer! :)